# Changing method variable while running a while loop

Tags: python, function, class, while-loop

I have stumbled upon a problem where i want to increment a variable inside a class **init** method while running through a continuous While loop.

My **init** method creates a rectangle and my other method draw(self) draws it on to the screen. Inside the While loop i increment the rectangle's y position by 7 (rect1.y += 7) and then call the draw method to print the object to screen.
Now, the problem is the object doesn't move down as intended and is static.

Note that the while loop is inside a function which basically updates the screen everytime and the Class is outside that function. I'm also initializing the instance with all it's attributes and calling the draw() method with that instance from inside the while loop.

Sorry if i don't explain this well but i hope you guys atleast get an idea of whats going on.

Any suggestions?

The class:

```
class Rect():

def __init__(self, color, x, y, w, h):
    self.color = color
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.w = w
    self.h = h

def draw(self):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h])
```

The code inside the while loop:

```
gameDisplay.fill(white)
rect1 = Rect(black, rect1_randomx, 200, 100, 100)
rect1.y += rect_speed
rect1.draw()
```

rect_speed = 7 is inside the function but NOT the while loop!

Comment: 2 separate local variables? we don't know because you don't show enough of the code.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is because you create

```
rect1 = Rect(black, rect1_randomx, 200, 100, 100)
```

inside `while` loop so you reset it all the time to start position.

You have to create `rect1` before `while`

Comment: I'll give you accept for this and thanks for the help!